# PHP redirect using cookies and headers

Tags: php, cookies, redirect, header

I was learning PHP and trying to redirect pages based on if the cookie is set or not so below is the code I used to set the cookie on the **first page**

```
<?php
setcookie("test","logged in",time()+60,'/');
?>
```

Now on the **testing page** I delete the cookie but it doesn't get deleted below is the code

```
<?php
setcookie("test", 0, time()-(60*60*24*7));

if(isset($_COOKIE['test']))
{
    echo "u had logged in";
}
else
header("Location: index.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

What exactly is the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are only set when a page is transmitted to the browser and are only read when they're sent to the server as a part of a HTTP request.

As such:

1. If you delete a cookie, it won't disappear until the next page load.
2. If you set a cookie, the value can't be read until the next page load.

A common way of dealing with this is to set/delete a cookie and then perform a re-direct.

Comment: a word of caution: do not simple reload the same page, as that will lead to circular redirects if someone has cookies disabled.

Comment: My recommendation is to send the user to an empty page where you set the cookie but produce no output and has minimal overhead, then use a header to change the location to the page with content that needs the cookie set.

Comment: After reloading I found that the problem persisted. So while setting the cookie, I removed the forward slash '/' (for setting the path) after setting the expiration and it worked. I didn't quite understand what was the problem with that slash ?

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to cookies are only visible to the server on refresh. If you reload the testing page, you shouldn't see the "logged in" text.

Comment: After reloading I found that the problem persisted. So while setting the cookie, I removed the forward slash '/' (for setting the path) after setting the expiration and it worked. I didn't quite understand what was the problem with that slash ?